# yandex api multiRouter Добавить информацию в балун

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Подскажите как добавить информацию в балун, который открывается по клику на маршрут. Как его вообще перехватить.
Например: подписываюсь на каждый маршрут

```
 multiRoute_<?=$key?>.events.add('click',
```

но в нем нет (либо я не знаю как достать ) самого объекта балун. Саму инфу достаю.
Или только делать кастомный?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Штатный балун изменить нельзя. Нужно реализовывать свой. Пример в песочнице Яндекса есть: https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_custom_balloon_layout/

Answer (score 1):

Карта с кучей маршрутов. Балуны убрал везде, вместо них открываю html окно, с нужной мне инфой. Изначально так и думал делать, но думал можно впихнуть в уже готовый балун свою инфу.